# How to get user names containing string in email and having a particular role

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-authorization

I know how to get the users in role

```
_userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("RequiredRole");
```

but how to find users with a part of the string? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could query the `ApplicationUser` list like below:

```
        var usersInRole = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Test").Result;
        if(usersInRole.Count>0)
        {
            //replace u.UserName if you need other logic
            var users = usersInRole.Where(u => u.Email.Contains(u.UserName)).ToList();
        }
```